# iterate an object and pass any keys of a specific value to an array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements, javascript-objects

I am trying to get specific keys of a certain value within an object into an array. When I specify the value the array is filled with all keys not just the ones that match the value. I only want the keys that have a value that matches my IF statement.  If my value doesn't match any of the values the array is empty, that works but if my value matches one f the keys then all keys are returned in the array, which is not what I want. I only want the key that matches the value of the key value pair.

```js
const chestSize = {
  "Leanne": 30,
  "Denise": 26,
  "Carol": 36,
  "Jill": 28,
  "Randy": 32
};

const chestSizeThirtySix = []

for (const key in chestSize) {
  if (chestSize[key] === 36) {
    chestSizeThirtySix.push(chestSize)
  }
};
console.log(chestSizeThirtySix)
```

Comment: Use `push(key)` instead of `push(chestSize)`

Comment: Ha, that simple. Thanks!

Comment: You even said it in the title: Pass keys to the array.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Object.entries` to implement this logic.

```js
const chestSize = {
  "Leanne": 30,
  "Denise": 26,
  "Carol": 36,
  "Jill": 28,
  "Randy": 32
};

const chestSizeThirtySix = Object.entries(chestSize)
  .filter(([key, value]) => value === 36)
  .map(([key, value]) => ({[key]:value}))
 
console.log(chestSizeThirtySix)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hugo Fang's example is good, but using a reduce will allow you to do the same process with only one loop through the array.

```js
const chestSize = {
  "Leanne": 30,
  "Denise": 26,
  "Carol": 36,
  "Jill": 28,
  "Randy": 32
};

const chestSizeThirtySix = Object.entries(chestSize)
  .reduce((r,[key,value]) => [...r, ...value === 36 ? [{[key]:value}] : []], [])

console.log(chestSizeThirtySix)
```